# ImageView in fixed position

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

In my `RelativeLayout`, I have a large background picture of an ocean view (`1870px` x `756px` in `drawable-xxhdpi`) that I center for all the devices :

```
<ImageView 
    android:src="@drawable/bg_image"
    android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ImageView>
```

On top of it, I want to put another Image of a ship (`500px` x `300px` also  in `drawable-xxhdpi`), centred horizontally, but should be `230px` away from the top of the screen to be on the horizon line.

```
<ImageView 
    android:src="@drawable/another_image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="230px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ImageView>
```

[image]

I'm not getting the correct results and android is complaining about the use of `px` as a unit for the margin top.

Results : Device 1 (adjusted on the horizon)

[image]

Smaller Device 2 (not adjusted on the horizon):

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the result you are getting, please specify

Comment: @Aakash I added more explanation, thanks

Comment: you have to fix image sizes for achieving this

Comment: @Aakash the images sizes are fixed, what do you mean by fix them?

Comment: I think it's better to use Frame layout instead of Relative layout.Have you tried?

Comment: i mean fix the height and width to certain dp instead of using wrap content or fill parent.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use "dp" unit... You could try using diferent devices (emulators, for example) with diferent sizes to guarantee it.

I hope this will help you

Comment: yes I tried px, dp and dip and it's never in the same position on the different emulators (I have one tablet and two phone simulators).

Comment: How about creating differents layouts? One layout for each display's size. Usually, developers do this

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that, cause then I'll need to animate the picture and that would be very tedious work

Comment: Yes, I agree but I think it is the best way

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the horizon on your background image is centered vertically. Then you can use this simple trick of `RelativeLayout` that will position your ship image above vertical center of the view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/bg_image"
        android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ImageView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/another_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/center">
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

each device has it's own screen resolution. I think you're using boat image with one screen resolution support. if you want to solve this problem you need to add boat image with different resolutions. Like HDPI,LDPI,MDPI,xhdpi